# Dynamic formula evaluation in JavaScript: eval() or not eval()

Tags: javascript, formula, eval

I'm working on a web application where an admin can define and adapt formulas that would need to be evaluated based on the input values (numbers) provided by the end users.

For the sake of clarity, here is a reduced example of what I would except:

```js
const obj = {
    type: "External wall in contact with the ground",
    layer: {
        base: {
            type: "Reinforced concrete (reinforcement 5 vol.%)",
            thickness: 100,                         // <-- user value
            lambda: 2.3,                            // <-- user value
            _r: "{{thickness}}/{{lambda}}/1000",    // <-- admin defined
            r: 0
        },
        waterproofing: {
            type: "Bitumen sheets (single layer)",
            share: 1,           // <-- user value
            _r: "{{share}}",    // <-- admin defined
            r: 0,
        },
        insulation: {
            type: "XPS",
            thickness: 100,                                 // <-- user value
            share: 1,                                       // <-- user value
            lambda: 0.040,                                  // <-- user value
            _r: "{{thickness}}*{{share}}/{{lambda}}/1000",  // <-- admin defined
            r: 0
        }
    }
}

Object.entries(obj.layer).forEach(([key, object]) => {
    var formula = object._r
    Object.keys(object).forEach(k =>
        formula = formula.replace(`{{${k}}}`, object[k])
    )

    obj.layer[key].r = eval(formula)
})

console.log(obj)
```

The `_r` is the formula defined by the admin. The `{{value}}` are the values provided by the end   users.

The loop goes through the `obj.layer` properties to evaluate the formula and save the answer in `r`.

The resulting would be this object:

```js
{
  type: 'External wall in contact with the ground',
  layer: {
    base: {
      type: 'Reinforced concrete (reinforcement 5 vol.%)',
      thickness: 100,
      lambda: 2.3,
      _r: '{{thickness}}/{{lambda}}/1000',
      r: 0.043478260869565216
    },
    waterproofing: {
      type: 'Bitumen sheets (single layer)',
      share: 1,
      _r: '{{share}}',
      r: 1
    },
    insulation: {
      type: 'XPS',
      thickness: 100,
      share: 1,
      lambda: 0.04,
      _r: '{{thickness}}*{{share}}/{{lambda}}/1000',
      r: 2.5
    }
  }
}
```

Let's skip the fact I don't validate the object structure and ensure all the values are available.

I know `eval()` is considered as "dangerous". A not-so good alternative would be `Function()`. Yet, not perfect.

So far, I see 3 possibilities:

1. Only the admin can alter the formulas. Therefore, the risk of executing evil code is very low. What I would need is to validate/sanitize the values (something like `isFloat()`), and that would be it.
2. Using the `mathjs` library, that offers a nice `evaluate()` function:

```js
const node2 = math.parse('x^a')
const code2 = node2.compile()
let scope = {
    x: 3,
    a: 2
}
code2.evaluate(scope) // 9
```

3. Use a parser generator like http://zaa.ch/jison/, but it seems overkill for what I want to do..

To be honest, I feel the use of `eval()` in my specific case is justified: dynamic formulas with dynamic values. I could use an external library like `mathjs` but I feel I don't need it for such simple operations.

I would really like to get your idea on the subject, and hear your suggestion if any !

*PS: Yes, the question has been asked already. Although, the most similar questions I found were asked (and responsed) several years ago. I would like to have a fresh input on that matter.*

---

**Based on @Sleavely answer, and further reading on the topic, `mathjs` seems the most reasonable solution to adopt ;-)**

Comment: how would you prevent users introducing problematic input?  https://xkcd.com/327/ will you sanitize?

Comment: Third-party admins may be the only ones who can _edit_ the code, but where will it actually run? In your backend? On visitors' computers? I strongly recommend you avoid eval(), lest you be blamed for whatever Bitcoin miner visitors end up contracting from your application.

With that in mind, I think that you're on the right track with your 2nd option. Evaluating the formula against a set of predefined variables strikes me as safe enough. Looks like `mathjs` actively avoids eval(): https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/master/docs/expressions/security.md

Comment: Might I suggest https://mathjs.org/index.html instead of using vanilla eval().

Comment: @malarres Yes I would certainly sanitize the input. Input should only be float.

Comment: @Sleavely Thanks for the links. Tbh, I was thinking mathjs was running `eval()` behind the scene. That's why I was wondering why adding a library if I can do "the same". I have the feeling `mathjs` is the middle-solution between the bad `eval()` and the complex(?) `jison` solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Sleavely answer (see comment quoted below), and further reading on the topic, `mathjs` seems the most reasonable solution:

> Third-party admins may be the only ones who can edit the code, but
> where will it actually run? In your backend? On visitors' computers? I
> strongly recommend you avoid eval(), lest you be blamed for whatever
> Bitcoin miner visitors end up contracting from your application. With
> that in mind, I think that you're on the right track with your 2nd
> option. Evaluating the formula against a set of predefined variables
> strikes me as safe enough. Looks like mathjs actively avoids eval():
> https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/master/docs/expressions/security.md